# How to check which line of Javascript issues HTTP request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

From Chrome Developers Tool, I can see there is a request to `http://www.example.com/abc`. I am sure it's an async request from my Javascript but I am not sure which line it is.

How to check the exact source of this request using Chrome Developers Tool

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Ensure that "Log XMLHttpRequests" is turned on in the settings for the console.
2. Have the console displayed
3. The line number and source URL for each request will be shown on the right hand side (and is hyperlinked)

[image: screenshot]